# React, onchange method doesnt update method parameter

Tags: reactjs, api, methods, onchange

Live searching with input. onChange method doesnt update parameter in getMovie method

```
constructor() {

this.getMovies('a');
}

getMovies(searchItem) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=...&query=' + searchItem
    })
}

onChange(e) {
    const searchItem = e.target.value
    this.getMovies(searchItem)
}


render(
    <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}></input> 
)
```

Comment: how do you know that it's not updating?

Comment: cause when I change 
this.getMovies('a') - > this.getMovies('avengers) 

In result component I can see different results

Comment: where is your code to show the results? currently there is no such api response handling

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to handle this kind of scenario regardless of how it is or isn't passing the correct parameter. You should absolutely throttle your ajax calls in some meaningful way otherwise it's going to drown the API in requests that you don't really care about anyways.
Regarding the question on hand, it's quite hard to help with the given details, mind to add some extra code to show how you realised that it doesn't change?  do you see any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Bombarding an API with a request per change on an input field is very poor practice. I think what you are trying to achieve is some sort of autocomplete styled input field.
Maybe try researching ['react-autosuggest'](https://react-autosuggest.js.org/). It would require an initial fetch to retrieve all name entries to fill an array/map etc., then your input field could traverse that with every change instead.